# accounts-entry for Angular in Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

[`accounts-entry`](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry) package works well when using Blaze and Meteor for having an alternative interface to the dropdown boxes for the login/signup forms.

How can we achieve the same style of using pages instead of dropdown boxes when using Angular with Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use existing Blaze packages and templates inside an Angular Meteor project, you will have to use the [angular-with-blaze](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/angular-with-blaze) package instead of the regular [angular](https://github.com/urigo/angular-meteor/) package.
That is because Meteor plugin system currently let you use one plugin per file type.
So with the `angular` package, we have a plugin that handles `.html` files and that means that Blaze html template will collide with that.
The `angular-with-blaze` package defines a plugin that compiles `.ng.html` files to Angular and then you can add the `blaze-html-templates` package to compile regular `html` files with Blaze and use any package you want.

If you want to include a Blaze template inside a `.ng.html` file, then you should use the [urigo:angular-blaze-template](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.0/blaze-template) package that let's you include Blaze templates inside Angular templates with an Angular directive.